# Dropping rows based on index and condition

Tags: python, pandas, rows, delete-row

I want to drop certain rows based off of range of rows: I feel like it would look something like the below

```
df.drop(df.index[[0,1,2,3]])
```

so that will just drop my first two rows but I would like to drop those rows if and only if that range of rows is blank. so

```
  Name

  Macy
  June

Jackson
```

So I would only want to go through the dataframe and drop rows in that range if and only if their is no data so my new dataframe would look like this:

```
  Name
  Macy
  June
Jackson
```

Comment: I don't see why you can't just do `df = df[df.Name.str.len() > 0]`

Comment: Alternatively, `df = df[df.Name.str.strip() == '']` - accounts for flexibility with spaces in entries.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `df.index` in the drop statement. However, if you only want to keep the rows where the `Name` column is filled, you just can use:

```
> df_filter = df [df.Name != '']
```

If you really want to locate the rows based on index, you can use

```
> df_filter = df.drop([0,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.ix` to get the excepted items, then drop the `None`s using `dropna()` method:

```
df.ix[indices].dropna()
```

Demo:

```
In [48]: df
Out[48]: 
      name
0     None
1     Macy
2     June
3     None
4  Jackson

In [49]: df.ix[[0,1,2,3]].dropna()
Out[49]: 
   name
1  Macy
2  June
```

Note: As mentioned in comment, since the `ix` method is deprecated you can use `df.loc()` instead.

Comment: `ix` is deprecated, you shouldn't advocate its use.